# How create vertical parallax background in android andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game in andegine and I want to create a parallax background that move from top to bottom in portrait mode but my parallax move from right to left or left to right. I have set my engine options to PORTRAIT_FIXED OR PORTRAIT_SENSOR. how do i achieve this task I have searched the options for AutoParallax and ParallaxEntity but there is no option to set portrait and landscape mode of parallax

Comment: You can you the horizontal one: ParallaxBackground class. copy it to a different class and change the following code: ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity.onDraw() function:

 final float cameraHeight = pCamera.getHeight();
    final float shapeHeightScaled =     this.mAreaShape.getHeightScaled();
    float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor) %     shapeHeightScaled;
      while(baseOffset > 0) {
   baseOffset -= shapeHeightScaled;
  }
  pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(0, baseOffset, 0);

  float currentMaxY = baseOffset;
...
(no more space, cannot format the code, sorry!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this - http://www.andengine.org/forums/post306324.html#p31347

The guy has created 2 new classes AutoVerticalParallaxBackground and VerticalParallaxBackground which do exactly what you want! (I am using it). So you can just use VerticalParallaxBackground or both depending on the result you like :).

A vertical parallax background can be implemented as:

```
mVerticalParallaxBackground = new VerticalParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
    mVerticalParallaxBackground.attachVerticalParallaxEntity(new VerticalParallaxEntity(-5.0f,
            new Sprite(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT
                    - mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad.getHeight(),
                    mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad,
                    mVertexBufferObjectManager)));

setBackground(mVerticalParallaxBackground);
```

My example of using this (for a AutoVerticalParallaxBackground):

```
mAutoVerticalParallaxBackground
            .attachVerticalParallaxEntity(new VerticalParallaxEntity(-5.0f,
                    new Sprite(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT
                            - mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad
                                    .getHeight(),
                            mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad,
                            mVertexBufferObjectManager)));

    setBackground(mAutoVerticalParallaxBackground);
```

I don't deserve any credit for this answer. I am putting it here so other people can find it easily!